# If implementation a producer/consumer model, what's the best data structure to use?

Tags: java

I thought a queue should be OK, the producer push back and the consumer take from front. Is there any other thoughts like thread safety etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a queue inside of a multithreaded environment, I suggest a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).
This will manage all the synchronization for you.